# Vuejs notification plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, vuejs2

I am writing for first time vuejs plugin in basic javascript (no ES).

Code looks like:

```
var NotificationStore =
{
state: [], // here the notifications will be added

removeNotification(timestamp)
{
    const indexToDelete = this.state.findIndex(n => n.timestamp === timestamp);

    if (indexToDelete !== -1)
        this.state.splice(indexToDelete, 1);
},
addNotification(notification)
{
    notification.timestamp = new Date();
    notification.timestamp.setMilliseconds(notification.timestamp.getMilliseconds() + this.state.length);

    this.state.push(notification);
},
notify(notification)
{
    if (Array.isArray(notification))
    {
        notification.forEach((notificationInstance) =>
        {
            this.addNotification(notificationInstance);
        });
    }
    else
        this.addNotification(notification);
}
}

var NotificationPlugin =
{
install(Vue, options)
{
    Vue.mixin(
    {
        data: function ()
        {
            var data =
                {
                    notificationStore: NotificationStore
                };

            return data;
        },
        methods:
        {
            notify(notification)
            {
                this.notificationStore.notify(notification);
            }
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, "$notify",
    {
        get() { return this.$root.notify }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, "$notifications",
    {
        get() { return this.$root.notificationStore }
    });

    Vue.component("notifications",
    {
        data()
        {
            return { notifications: this.$notifications.state };
        },
        methods:
        {
            removeNotification (timestamp)
            {
                this.$notifications.removeNotification(timestamp);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Problem is when I write into console following command:

```
app.$notify({message:"Hello",type:"success",icon:"",horizontalAlign:"right",verticalAlign:"bottom"});
```

I get error:

```
vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'notificationStore' of undefined"
```

If I run chrome debugger I can see object is accessible. Error is printed to console on Vue.mixins data() return command.

I can't see there any issue, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Vue.mixin(
    {
        data: function ()
        {
            return {
                    notificationStore: NotificationStore
            };
        },
        methods:
        {
            notify(notification)
            {
                this.notificationStore.notify(notification);
            }
        }
    });
```

instead:

```
Vue.mixin(
    {
        data: function ()
        {
            var data =
                {
                    notificationStore: NotificationStore
                };

            return data;
        },
        methods:
        {
            notify(notification)
            {
                this.notificationStore.notify(notification);
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to reply your code working and if dont use `return {}` without break line anfter return, then doesn't work.